# Standardising mean for variables and correct statistical approach

Tags: r, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, poisson-regression, log-linear

I'm working with data set which is highly skewed and not sure whether it is the the right approach to standardise the mean fro both dependent and independent variables. The aim is to find out if climate variables could be predictors for disease cases.

The other question is with poisson model one would use quasipoisson or negative binomial  etc to handle over-dispersion. Which test would one use in my case for the output bellow where obviously there is overdispersion. Thanks

### centering on mean

>

```
 orf$new_maxtemp11 = maxtemp11-mean(maxtemp11, na.rm=TRUE)
    > orf$new_mintemp11 = mintemp11-mean(mintemp11, na.rm=TRUE)
> orf$new_meantemp11 = meantemp11-mean(meantemp11, na.rm=TRUE)
    > orf$new_rain2011 = rain2011-mean(rain2011, na.rm=TRUE)
> orf$new_Altitude = Altitude-mean(Altitude, na.rm=TRUE)
    > orf$new_Cases2011=Cases2011-mean(Cases2011,na.rm=TRUE)



Call:
    glm(formula = log(new_Cases2011 + 0.01) ~ new_maxtemp11 + new_mintemp11 + 
        new_meantemp11 + new_rain2011, data = orf)

    Deviance Residuals: 
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    -3.7158  -1.0434  -0.0591   1.2671   3.4029  

    Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)     3.814062   0.213980  17.824   <2e-16 ***
    new_maxtemp11  -2.388755   1.239218  -1.928   0.0587 .  
    new_mintemp11  -0.640589   0.725181  -0.883   0.3806    
    new_meantemp11  3.512886   2.035095   1.726   0.0896 .  
    new_rain2011   -0.006123   0.006084  -1.006   0.3183    
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 2.820822)

        Null deviance: 180.61  on 63  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance: 166.43  on 59  degrees of freedom
      (232 observations deleted due to missingness)
    AIC: 254.79
```

Comment: Can you say more about how you would standardize the mean? My understanding is you could transform the DV (i.e., with a square root or log function) if it is not normally distributed, but not center or standardize it. Although you could center or standardize the IV, I think that transforming it may be the better approach than to center or standardize it, if it's not normally distributed. Finally, not sure about what you mean about over dispersion. What are the units of your DV?

Comment: @Joshua Rosenberg, sorry for the late reply. Someone advised that I  standardize the values given there were variations e.g temperature = 13 degree Celsius while rain = 1000 milimiters. with over-dispersion I was looking at  Residual deviance  being greater t59  degrees of freedom